Benchmark for loop and deque/map/methodcaller
While discussing with some colleagues, one argued that a for loop over a list of objects to call a method is a bad practice because it has bad performance compared to deque(map(methodcaller()).
He did not support his claim with a benchmark.  I did one myself.
Here is the setup:
import collections
import operator

import pyperf


class Do:
    def nothing(self):
        pass


dos = [Do() for _ in range(10000)]

And functions I'll benchmark:
def with_for_loop():
    for do in dos:
        do.nothing()


def with_deque_map():
    collections.deque(
        map(operator.methodcaller("nothing"), dos),
        maxlen=0,
    )

From a Pythonic point of view, if performance are not a requirement, I think the for loop is better by far. But I'm looking for a performance point of view.
I would expect the difference in an algorithm, minimal if significant, in favor of the deque/map/methodcaller.
But here are the results:
.....................
for_loop: Mean +- std dev: 244 us +- 8 us
.....................
deque_map: Mean +- std dev: 1.09 ms +- 0.02 ms

(same time difference with larger list)
Did I do something wrong with the benchmark?
Is the overhead of methodcaller big enough to make this this slow?
I don't understand this result.

When Do.nothing() is a static method:
class Do:
    @staticmethod
    def nothing():
        pass

The performance gap get smaller:
.....................
for_loop: Mean +- std dev: 395 us +- 13 us
.....................
deque_map: Mean +- std dev: 712 us +- 10 us

Here, the for loop get slower, and the other get faster than before. I think that the fact that Do.nothing is a static method should make both faster, since there is no need to instantiate a bound method
I don't understand why the for loop get slower.

If you want to run the benchmark yourself:

Install pyperf: pip install pyperf
And ehre is the full script:

import collections
import operator

import pyperf


class Do:
    def nothing(self):
        pass


dos = [Do() for _ in range(10000)]


def with_for_loop():
    for do in dos:
        do.nothing()


def with_deque_map():
    collections.deque(
        map(operator.methodcaller("nothing"), dos),
        maxlen=0,
    )


def pyperf_bench():
    runner = pyperf.Runner()
    runner.bench_func(
        name="for_loop",
        func=with_for_loop,
    )
    runner.bench_func(
        name="deque_map",
        func=with_deque_map,
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyperf_bench()


Notes:
deque with maxlen of 0 consume the map iterable without storing anything. docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects It's a known recipe to consume an generator (look at "consume" recipe): docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

I have a feeling that with Do.nothing instead of operator.methodcaller('nothing') should bring them closer (probably still slower though).

With regards to your benchmark that uses two different methods to invoke a method on each element of an iterable of objects, then note that:

In with_for_loop you are able to "directly" call method do_nothing simply and efficiently with do.do_nothing().
In with_deque_map you are invoking the do_nothing method in each iteration using the built-in map with operator.methodcaller, which are more or less necessitated by using a deque instance to implicitly do the iteration for you. But the mechanics use to perform the method call on each iteration this way incurs additional overhead not present in with_for_loop.

So if you would like to benchmark two different methods of invoking a method call on an iterable containing object references, then I am not surprised to find that with_deque_map performs worse than with_for_loop because of the use of map with operator_methodcaller. Let's not consider a benchmark that measures the two methods of iterating an iterable of values without performing function calls, then I would modify the benchmark as follows:
import collections

import pyperf


iterable = [x for x in range(10_000)]


def with_for_loop():
    for _ in iterable:
        pass


def with_deque():
    collections.deque(
        iterable,
        maxlen=0,
    )

def pyperf_bench():
    runner = pyperf.Runner()
    runner.bench_func(
        name="with_for_loop",
        func=with_for_loop,
    )
    runner.bench_func(
        name="with_deque",
        func=with_deque,
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyperf_bench()

The output is:
with_for_loop: Mean +- std dev: 108 us +- 18 us
with_deque: Mean +- std dev: 25.0 us +- 1.8 us

You can clearly see that using a deque instance now performs significantly better than using an explicit for loop. But if you have to use the built-in map function with the operator.methodcaller method to invoke method do_nothing on an iterable of objects just to be able to use the "consume" recipe, you discover that you will be better off not using the recipe at all.
